# "for /f .... do" doesn't work on the first line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I use the following batch file to delete files with full path. The first line of the output file is an error message "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." All files in C:\DELETE-ALL-FULLPATH.txt are deleted except the first one. I wonder why the first line causes the problem.

```
@REM This script deletes files which include full path.

@if exist C:\DELETE-all-fullpath-output.txt DEL /Q c:\DELETE-all-fullpath-output.txt
@for /f "tokens=* eol=@ delims=" %%A in ( C:\DELETE-ALL-FULLPATH.txt) do (
@DEL /Q /A "%%A"
)   >> C:\DELETE-all-fullpath-output.txt 2>&1

CD /D C:\
```

These are the first two lines of C:\DELETE-ALL-FULLPATH.txt. All lines have the same format except the numbers are different. All the listed files are deleted except the first one.

```
c:\Users\administrator\documents\IMG_20190229_134600.jpg
c:\Users\administrator\documents\IMG_20191229_134202.jpg
......
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps file is unicode and has a byte order mark at the start of the first line, that isn't handled when it is being read?

Comment: @Gerhard I got `C:\>(echo /Q /A "c:\Users\administrator\documents\IMG_20190229_134600.jpg" ) 1>>C:\DELETE-all-fullpath-output.txt 2>&1` Doesn't seem to be a problem there.

Comment: @Lasse very likely. I added a blank line as the first line, ran the batch file again, and the first file was deleted although the error message was still there.

Comment: @Lasse Actually, the error message is `Could Not Find C:\`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try please.

```
@echo off
REM This script deletes files which include full path.
del /Q c:\DELETE-all-fullpath-output.txt>nul 2>&1
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("C:\DELETE-ALL-FULLPATH.txt") do (
    if exist "%%~A" del /Q /A "%%~A"
)>>c:\DELETE-all-fullpath-output.txt 2>&1
```

**EDIT**

After reviewing your file, it indeed is UTF-8 with BOM enabled.

[image]

Open the file in notepad, then select save as. in the encoding tab, select UTF-8 only, without BOM.

Comment: Sure. But first try if this link would work. I have uploaded the file to Dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/oh6ojtyu2aht6w2/delete-all-FULLPATH.txt?dl=0

Comment: Now, the file in the first line is deleted.

Comment: ok, so to best explain it, just read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom#:~:text=The%20UTF%2D8%20BOM%20is,8%2C%20the%20BOM%20is%20unnecessary.)